# Trying to add an AD group to an alert

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, alert

I am trying to add an existing AD group to an alert for a list, however, it does not appear in the dropdown.

When I add the email directly i get a `"Sorry, you are not allowed to share this with external users."`

I checked and each user has an email with `@ourdomain.com` or `@ourdomain.com.mx.`
The group is set as a security group, and as I mentioned, it has an email address.

What could be preventing the AD group from populating and being accepted.
This is for a SharePoint 2013 On-premises installation.

Comment: Maybe you could add a new SharePoint permission group based on read and then add the AD group there and then assign it to the alert?

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is a noted bug a year ago. their is workaround for this.
[Setting SharePoint Alerts on Active Directory Security Groups](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/10/setting-sharepoint-alerts-on-active-directory-security-groups/)

I'm suggesting that you try adding the AD group by giving it permissions directly to see if SharePoint will recognize it like a user.  As I said, alerts are designed to work with users, not groups or distribution lists.  If you can trick SharePoint into thinking the group is a user it might work. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2fbca926-b57d-42a7-a3f4-75e96decaed7/sharepoint-2013-create-sharepoint-alerts-for-ad-groups

Answer (score 0):

with SharePoint 2010 and 2013 out of the box features, it is not simple to select custom recipients, AD users, personalize templates and mail merge information from multiple lists. 
If you are not willing to use complex SharePoint Workflows or waste time for coding, the possibilities are quite limited. In this case I would recommend to use a 3rd party tool, to extend the SharePoint alert feature. You can find some options in the market, but I am using [JungleBell](http://blog.enovapoint.com/post/JungleBell-Mail-Merge-SharePoint-Alerts-from-Multiple-Lists)